# Is cosine a function of sine?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Suppose we are working over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Is the cosine function $\cos(x)$ a function of the sine function $\sin(x)$? I define a function $f$ to be a function of a function $g$ if there is a function $h$ such that $h$ composed with $g$, in that order, equals $f$.

Comment: Note that $\sin(0) = \sin(\pi)$ and $\cos(0) \neq \cos(\pi)$.

Comment: Note that when $\sin(x)=0$, $\cos(x)=1$ or $-1$

Comment: but when $0\le x\lt \dfrac \pi 2$, let $h(s)=\sqrt{1-s^2}$

Comment: in a sense you probably didn't intend, one could use $h = - \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's a nice note, but $h(g(x))$ isn't $h(g)(x)$.  I've seen notations where these two can be confused, but I definitely wouldn't call an operator applied to a function, the "operator composed with the function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there were a function $h$ such that $\cos = h \circ \sin$, then we'd have
$$-1 = \cos(\pi) = h\circ \sin(\pi) = h(\sin(\pi)) = h(\sin(0)) = h\circ \sin(0) = \cos(0) = 1$$

This is contradictory, so no such $h$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

The "co" in cosine stands for "complementary".  In a right triangle, if you take the sine of one of the acute angles, the cosine of that angle is the sine of the complementary acute angle, i.e. "complementary sine".  So you could subtract an acute angle in a right triangle from 90$^\circ$ and then take the sine of that to get the cosine of the original angle, which I guess would be a 2-step function, but it's far simpler to just go with adjacent/hypotenuse or x/r in circular form.

Comment: $\cos(\theta) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$